# How do I use a closure for each JS file, but still have the files interact with each other.

Tags: javascript, closures, iife

I understand that using closures (IIFE) is the best practice as it prevents polluting the global namespace.  However, when I added the closures to my files, it prevented my 2nd file (controllers.js) from reading the first file (models.js).  To give you an idea, here's what they look like:

**models.js**

```
;(function() {
  function searchResult (obj) {
    this.state = obj.State;
    /*Do more stuff */
  }

})();
```

**controllers.js**

```
;(function() {
 function storeSearchResults(jsonObj) {
   var instance = new searchResult(jsonObj.data[i]);
   /* Do more */
 }     
})();
```

Now that I've added closures on them, I'm getting an error that `searchResult` is undefined in  controllers.js -- because it can't see that it exists in the models.js.  How do I get it to understand that it exists in the other file?

P.S.  Yes, models.js is added in the HTML file before the controllers.js file.

Comment: You can use a module system, like http://requirejs.org/ (AMD) or http://browserify.org/ (CommonJS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For them to interact, they have to have some common symbol. You have a couple of choices:

1. Do it yourself (using a single global variable)
2. Use some kind of library that does it for you (using [ideally] just a single global symbol)
3. Do it yourself a different way that requires no global common symbol *at all*

#### Do it yourself

The DIY version is, typically, that you have a *single* global, for your entire app, which your various modules add properties to.

So for instance:

models.js:

```
;(function(globals) {
  var MyApp = globals.MyApp = globals.MyApp || {};
  MyApp.searchResult = searchResult;
  function searchResult (obj) {
    this.state = obj.State;
    /*Do more stuff */
  }

})(this);
```

That works because in loose mode, `this` at global scope is the global object (`window` on browsers). We pass it into the IIFE as the argument `globals`, and then either use or create a property on it called `MyApp`, and add `searchResult` to it as a property.

controllers.js:

```
;(function(globals) {
  var MyApp = globals.MyApp = globals.MyApp || {};
  function storeSearchResults(jsonObj) {
    var instance = new MyApp.searchResult(jsonObj.data[i]);
    /* Do more */
 }     
})(this);
```

We do the same thing, except that `controllers.js` is expecting that `models.js` has already been run. Although we still do the `var MyApp = globals.MyApp = globals.MyApp || {};` bit, the `new MyApp.searchResult` would of course fail if `models.js` hadn't been run.

There are probably a dozen syntactic variations on this theme, this is just one of them.

#### Use some kind of library that does it for you

Your other option is to use a library like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) (the one global symbol there is `require`, and it's a function) or any other [asynchronous module definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition) lib.

#### Do it yourself another way

Another DIY option gets rid of globals *entirely*, you don't even need a single global.

To do that, your individual files don't have the IIFE (although they can use ones for things they don't want to share with other files):

```
;
function searchResult (obj) {
  this.state = obj.State;
  /*Do more stuff */
}
```

controllers.js:

```
;
function storeSearchResults(jsonObj) {
  var instance = new searchResult(jsonObj.data[i]);
  /* Do more */
}
```

Then you use a minifier to combine your scripts **and** wrap them in one big IIFE. You might have `pre.js`:

```
(function() {
```

and `post.js`:

```
})();
```

Then the minifier creates `app.js` by combining `pre.js + models.js + controllers.js + post.js`. The end result (un-minified and formatted here for readability) is:

```
(function() {
    ;
    function searchResult (obj) {
      this.state = obj.State;
      /*Do more stuff */
    }

    ;
    function storeSearchResults(jsonObj) {
      var instance = new searchResult(jsonObj.data[i]);
      /* Do more */
    }
})();
```

I called this DIY, but I wouldn't be surprised if there were tools to help with it.

Comment: Thanks @TJ, your solved my issue! Two questions that I have for the sake of understanding are: 1.) What is the `(this)` argument at the end of each IIFE for?  and 2.) How is `controllers.js` able to understand where to get the `global` parameter from -- since no one is explicitly calling it?

Comment: @ayjay: At the top level of a `script` block, if you are not using `"use strict"`, `this` is the global object (aka `window` on browsers; technically, `window` is a property on the global object -- a global variable -- that it uses to refer to itself). So by passing `this` into our IIFE, we can reference it with the argument name `global`. (I would typically use `"use strict"` at the top of the IIFE, so that the code within the function was strict mode, as strict mode is quite handy. But *outside* the IIFE, I like to use `this` rather than `window`, as it's not browser-specific.

Comment: Thanks, and I have a Follow up question... is there a reason why you chose a 3-level deep definition (i.e., `global.MyApp.searchResult`) as opposed to 2 (i.e., `global.searchResult`?  I'm wondering if using 3-level is a best practice approach.

Comment: @ayjay: It's so we only have one global: `MyApp`. I think my naming of the argument in the code above was really confusing (I used `global` as in "the global object" which is what contains global variables), so I've changed it to `globals` (because the "global object" contains global variables). Also, I added a `var MyApp = ` in front of the bit that sets up `globals.MyApp` so we can use `MyApp` within the IIFE. Updated pastie as well: http://pastie.org/9315636 Any property we put on `globals` becomes a global variable, so we want to keep that to a minimum (zero if possible, one in the above).

Comment: I have another question that's related to the response you've provided (btw, I really appreciate all the responses).  When dealing with namespaces between files, which approach is more commonly used: [Approach A](http://pastie.org/9642928) OR [Approach B](http://pastie.org/9642927)? I understand both works, but am curious which convention is more followed in the real world.

Comment: @ayjay: I don't know which is more common. *Perhaps* Approach B or any of a dozen variants of it: http://pastie.org/9643560

Comment: Thanks for the pastie!  One quick question, what does the term `prev` stand for? Is it Previous?

Comment: @ayjay: Yup. Could be `MODELS`, that would be fine.

Answer (score -2):

Events and listeners passing and receiving data.

I don't use globals.

However I don't know how to use events in raw javascript or if data passing can be done. I use jquery/node which allow for passing data and just works beautifully.